# Sending a Field across visualforce based on the row user's clicked

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to send a id across from a table to the controller based off what you row you press. Here is a link that I have used to make the table. http://www.forcetree.com/2010/04/expand-collapse-pageblock-table-columns.html

Here is what I have so far for the visual force page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="myEmployeeController3">
<apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
    <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

    <style>
        p { font-weight: bold; }
        p {font-size: 15px;}
        h1,h2 {display:block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;}
        h1 {font-size: 20px;}
        h2 {font-size: 16px;}
        #inputSection {text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;}

    </style>
    <script>
    function myFunction(myId) {
        myActionFunction(myId);
    }

    function switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2) 
    {
        var el = document.getElementById(obj);                                       
        if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            el.style.display = '';
        }
        var e2 = document.getElementById(obj1);                                       
        if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
            e2.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            e2.style.display = '';
        }
        var e3 = document.getElementById(obj2);                                       
        if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
            e3.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            e3.style.display = '';
        }

    }
    </script>

    <apex:form >

        <h1>Permissions Inspector</h1>
        <h2>Enter Object API Name</h2>

        <div id="inputSection">
            <apex:inputText value="{!SObjectName}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!actionSupMethod}" reRender="test2" value="Submit"/>
        </div>

        <apex:actionfunction name="myActionFunction" action="{!submitLead}">
            <apex:param name="recordId" value=""/>
        </apex:actionfunction>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="test2" value="{!objectout}" var="cus" >
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">                                        
                        THE RESULTS ARE                                                                             
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputpanel id="plusimage">
                        <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" onclick="switchMenu
                                                                           ('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}')" title="Expand"/> 
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                    <apex:outputpanel id="minusimage" style="display:none;">
                        <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Minus_Image}"
                                    onclick="switchMenu('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!$Component.minusimage}')" title="Collapse"/>
                    </apex:outputpanel>

                    <apex:outputpanel id="inlinetablesec" style="display:none;">
                        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                        <apex:repeat var="count" value="{!cus.Parent.Profile.Name}">
                            <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
                            <apex:commandButton value="Save2" onclick="myFunction('AM');" reRender="LDB"/>
                        </apex:repeat> <!-- Send partnerid to the controller based on Parent.Profile.Name-->
                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!rowNum=0}">  Element Set Null </apex:outputText>

                        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!cus.ParentId}" var="tm" rendered="{!rowNum>0}" >
                        </apex:pageblocktable>
                    </apex:outputpanel>     
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Object" value="{!cus.SObjectType}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Read" value="{!cus.PermissionsRead}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Parent ID" value="{!cus.ParentId}"/> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Edit" value="{!cus.PermissionsEdit}"/>p
                <apex:column headerValue="Delete" value="{!cus.PermissionsDelete}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="ViewAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsViewAllRecords}"/> 
                <apex:column headerValue="ModifyAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsModifyAllRecords}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="LDB">
                Passed parameter in Form: {!parent} <br/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public with sharing class myEmployeeController3 {
public String SObjectName{get;set;}

public String SObjectName1{get;set;}

public List<ObjectPermissions> objectout{get;set;}
public List<ObjectPermissions> objectout1{get;set;}
public List<FieldPermissions> fieldPerms{get;set;}
public List<Id> rParentIds = new List<Id>();

private Map<Id,List<FieldPermissions>> FieldPermMap = new Map<Id,List<FieldPermissions>>();

public String parent{get; set;}
public String recordId{get; set;}

public PageReference submitLead() {

    return null;
}

public myEmployeeController3(){
    recordId =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordId');
    System.debug('record' +recordId);
    parent = recordId;
}

//try list<> return the list
Public void actionSupMethod(){

    objectout =  [SELECT Parent.Id, Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsDelete,
                  PermissionsViewAllRecords,PermissionsModifyAllRecords
                  FROM ObjectPermissions 
                  WHERE SObjectType = :SObjectName AND (PermissionsRead = true OR PermissionsCreate = true 
                                                        OR PermissionsEdit = true OR PermissionsDelete = true 
                                                        OR PermissionsViewAllRecords = true OR PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true)
                  ORDER BY Parent.IsOwnedByProfile ASC];

    fieldPerms = [SELECT  Field FROM FieldPermissions
                  WHERE  Parent.Id= '00eF0000001CAofIAG' AND SObjectType = 'contact'
                  ORDER BY Field DESC];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You was very close. Instead of calling JS from button save2, 
you could pass your field directly through button with help of apex:param.

Apex:param will assign its value *cus.parentid* to controller property *recordId*:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save2" action="{!submitLead}" reRender="LDB">
    <apex:param name="passing id" value="{!cus.parentid}" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

In apex you could modify recordId type and add debug in submitLead function:

```
public Id recordId{get; set;}

public void submitLead() {
    System.debug('record' +recordId);
}
```

Comment: I am confused. You examples after the OR and the Apex do not reflect what you make in your opening statement. Maybe you could clarify your answer a bit more to make it more effective for the OP?